# When should a trig function, with a degree argument, return -0.0?

Tags: c, math

In creating trig functions `my_sind(d)`, `my_cosd(d)`, `my_tand(d)`, that used a degree argument rather than a radian one and provided exact answers at multiples of 90, I noticed that the result was sometimes `-0.0` rather than `0.0`.

```
my_sind( 0.0) -->  0.0
my_sind(-0.0) --> -0.0

my_sind(180.0) --> -0.0
my_sind(360.0) -->  0.0
```

`sin()` and `tan()` typically return the same sign zero result for a given sign zero input.  It makes sense that `my_sin()` should match `sin()` for those inputs.

```
my_sind( 0.0) alike sin( 0.0) -->  0.0
my_sind(-0.0) alike sin(-0.0) --> -0.0
```

**The question is**: for what whole number `non_zero_n` should/may the result ever return `-0.0` for `my_sind(180*non_zero_n)`, `my_cosd(180*n + 180)`, `my_tand(180*non_zero_n)`?

It is easy enough to code so only `f(-0.0)` produces `-0.0` and be done with it.  Simple wondering if there is any reason to make <strike>other</strike> `f(x)` return `-0.0` for any other (**non-zero**) `x` and the importance of insuring that sign.

---

Note: This is not a question of why `0.0` vs. `-0.0` occurs.  This is not why `cos(machine_pi/4)` does not return `0.0`.  Neither is this a question of how to control the generation of `0.0` or `-0.0`.  I see it best as a design question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The design principle of "least surprise" suggests that we look to previously established functionality for guidance. In this case, the closest established functionality is provided by `sinpi` and `cospi` functions introduced in IEEE Std 754-2008 (the IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic), section 9. These functions are not part of the current ISO C and ISO C++ standards, but have been incorporated into the math libraries of various programming platforms, for example CUDA.

These functions compute sin(πx) and cos(πx), where multiplication with π occurs implicitly inside the function. `tanpi` is not defined, but could, based on mathematical equivalency, be assumed to provide functionality according to `tanpi(x) = sinpi(x) / cospi(x)`.

We can now define `sind(x) = sinpi(x/180)`, `cosd(x) = cospi(x/180)`, `tand(x) = tanpi(x/180)` in an intuitive manner. Section 9.1.2 of IEEE-754 spells out the handling of special arguments for `sinpi` and `cospi`. In particular:

> sinPi(+n) is +0 and sinPi(−n) is −0 for positive integers n. This
>   implies, under appropriate rounding modes, that sinPi(−x) and
>   −sinPi(x) are the same number (or both NaN) for all x. cosPi(n + ½) is
>   +0 for any integer n when n + ½ is representable.

The IEEE 754-2008 standard does not give a rationale for the quoted requirements, however, an early [draft](http://www.christoph-lauter.org/revisionIEEE754.txt) of the relevant section states:

> If the value of the function is zero, the sign of this 0 is best determined by considering the continuous extension of the sign function of the mathematical function.

Perusal of the [754 Working Group Mail Archive](http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754/email/) may yield additional insights, I have not had the time to dig through it. Implementing `sind()`, `cosd()`, and `tand()` as described above, we then arrive at this table of example cases:

```
SIND
 angle value 
  -540 -0
  -360 -0
  -180 -0
     0  0
   180  0
   360  0
   540  0

COSD
 angle value
  -630  0
  -450  0
  -270  0
   -90  0
    90  0
   270  0
   450  0

TAND
 angle value
  -540  0
  -360 -0
  -180  0
     0  0
   180 -0
   360  0
   540 -0
```

Answer (score 5):

> sin() and tan() typically return the same sign zero result for a given sign zero input

It could be generally true since:

- **Speed/accuracy**. For small enough doubles, the best answer for `sin(x)` is `x`. That is, for numbers smaller than about `1.49e-8`, the closest double to the sine of x is actually x itself (see the [glibc source code for sin()](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/s_sin.c;hb=HEAD#l281)).
- **Handling of special cases**.

  > A few extraordinary arithmetic operations are affected by zero's sign;
  >   for example `"1/(+0) = +inf"` but `"1/(-0) = -inf"`. To retain its
  >   usefulness, the sign bit must propagate through certain arithmetic
  >   operations according to rules derived from continuity considerations.
  >
  > Implementations of elementary transcendental functions like sin(z) and
  >   tan(z) and their inverses and hyperbolic analogs, though not specified by
  >   the IEEE standards, are expected to follow similar rules.
  >   The implementation of `sin(z)` **is expected to reproduce the sign of `z`
  >   as well as its value at `z = ±O`**.

  <sup>([Branch Cuts for Complex Elementary Functions or Much Ado About Nothing's Sign Bit](http://people.freebsd.org/~das/kahan86branch.pdf) by W. Kahan)</sup>

  Negatively signed zero echoes the mathematical analysis concept of approaching 0 from below as a one-sided limit (consider `1 / sin(x)`: the sign of zero makes a huge difference).

EDIT

Considering the second point I'd write `my_sind` so that:

```
my_sind(-0.0) is -0.0
my_sind(0.0) is 0.0
```

The latest C standard (F.10.1.6 `sin` and F.10.1.7 `tan`, implementations with a signed zero), specifies that if the argument is `±0`, [it is returned unmodified](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/sin).

EDIT 2

For the other values I think it's a matter of approximation. Given `M_PI` < π:

```
0 = sin(π) < sin(M_PI) ≈ 1.2246467991473532e-16 ≈ +0.0
0 = sin(-π) > sin(-M_PI) ≈ -1.2246467991473532e-16 ≈ -0.0
0 = sin(2*π) > sin(2*M_PI) ≈ -2.4492935982947064e-16
0 = sin(-2*π) < sin(-2*M_PI) ≈ 2.4492935982947064e-16
```

So if `my_sind` provides exact answers at multiples of 180° it can return `+0.0` or `-0.0` (I don't see a clear reason to prefer one over the other).

If `my_sind` uses some approximation (e.g. a `degree * M_PI / 180.0` conversion formula), it should consider how it's approaching the critical values.

Comment: What are your thoughts concerning `sind(180), sind(-180), sind(360), sind(-360),...`?

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Maybe my post is not clear.  The main question is should `my_trig(x)` ever return `-0.0` when `|x|` is not `0.0`?

Comment: Thanks for the "So if my_sind provides exact answers at multiples of 180° it can return +0.0 or -0.0 (I don't see a clear reason to prefer one over the other)."  It is the closest discussion point so far.  I'm thinking that "principle of least astonishment" encourages always returning `+0.0`, but looking to see if there are compelling reasons to return `-0.0` in some situations (other than `x == +/-0.0`).

Comment: @chux: I think for multiples of `180.0`, one really has to examine the values of relative machine precision given those values. That is, the smallest increment/decrement that gives a different representable value in that numerical format. Then, compare that value with the true value to see whether it would fall on the plus side or minus side.

Comment: @rwong Thanks for the idea.  Multiples of 90.0 _degrees_, the _exact_ `sind(double degrees)` and `cosd(double degrees)` value can be returned: `-1.0, +0.0, +1.0`.  This post is about should `-0.0` ever be returned (aside from sind(-0.0)).  Note: `sind()` does _not_ use the simplistic `sin(x/360*M_PI)` approach.

Answer (score 3):

> The library doesn't try to distinguish +0 from -0. IEEE 754 worries
>   quite a bit about this distinction...I found the functions [in math.h]
>   quite hard enough to write without fretting about the sign of nothing.
>   -- P.J. Plauger, *The Standard C Library*, 1992, page 128.

Formally, trig functions should return the sign of zero in accord with the C standard...which leaves the behavior undefined.

In the face of undefined behavior, [the principle of least astonishment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187457/what-is-the-principle-of-least-astonishment) suggests duplicating the behavior of the corresponding function from `math.h`. This smells justifiable, while diverging from the behavior of the corresponding function in `math.h` smells like a way to introduce bugs into exactly the code which depends on the sign of zero.

Comment: The trig functions in `math.h` do not return 0.0 when given arguments like  +/-pi/2 or +/-pi as these functions can only take representable values _near_ +/-pi/2,etc.  These "near" values return results near 0.0.  Since the std library trig functions (`sin cos tan`) do not return 0.0 (or -0.0) for any input (except +/-0.0), but my_sind(), my_cosd(), my_tand() can return 0.0 (or -0.0) there is no 0.0 behavior to duplicate.

Comment: @chux The premise that `sin(-0.0)` should return `-0` is suspect. It treats an implementation detail of the IEEE standard as a trigonometric principle. Although there is a general mathematical principle of zero as the limit of two intervals embodied in the IEEE implementation, it occurs at that level of abstraction not within general trigonometry [hence the variability in what your trigonometric functions return]. The best that can happen is that you can define an arbitrary convention, but it will be divergent from `math.h`'s nonchalance over the sign of zero.

Comment: Note: I am not suggesting `sin(-0.0)` should return `-0.0`, but that `my_sind(x)` should match `sin(x)` when `x` is `+/-0.0`.  IOW: follow previous practice.  Further the question itself is more about what to do when `x != 0.0`, should `my_sind(x)` ever return `-0.0` as in `my_sind(180)`, etc?  Maybe your answer / comment addresses that - but I have not seen that.

Comment: @chux If the behavior is undefined, then it's undefined. That's just the way C is. Plauger didn't worry about `+0` versus `-0` when he wrote `math.h` twenty years ago. It's not clear to me what problem your fretting about the difference is solving.

Comment: @chux The principle of least astonishment suggests that outside of the special cases, `my_sind()` should be implemented in terms of `sin()`. Perhaps with extra precision to handle conversion in floating between alternative representations of the same values.

Comment: Hopefully you see that for a well implemented `sin(rad)` for any value `rad>0` and of any precision will never yield `0.0` as pi is irrational.  [Ref](www.csee.umbc.edu/~phatak/645/supl/Ng-ArgReduction.pdf) However `my_sind(deg)` yields an exact `0.0` (either + or -) every multiple of `180.0` as the value 0.0 is the correct mathematical result.  "Principle of least astonishment" suggests returning 0.0 in these cases.  My question is should `-0.0` ever be returned in these cases?

Comment: @chux In C Pi is defined in math.h: `#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846`. Anyone is free to define `sin()` such that if `x % PI` is zero `sin` returns `+0`. Or `-0`. However, doing so would arbitrary whether the input is in degrees or not. If you can't live with a multivalent zero, arbitrary precision numbers are probably a better choice than floating point. TANSTAAFL: the speed of floating point has a price.

Comment: Defining `sin(x) == +/-0.0` when `x % M_PI == 0` would be a substandard `sin()` implementation.  A robust `sin()` assumes the input is infinity precise and generates the best answer for _that_ number.  Since M_PI is not pi, the expected answer is `2.64...e-21 or 1.22...e-16, etc.` but not `0.0`.  Good `sin()` uses a pi and mod operation to a precision exceeding the argument type.  `my_sind(180.0) --> 0.0` without the need for very high level of FP precision: works even with `float`.